# Un-readable core dump after segmentation fault

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, debian-squeeze, segmentation-fault

I have the following problem on my `LAMP(hp)` stack, from time to time I get `Segmentation fault`. So I made core dump in my `Debian Squeeze` and I hoped that it will tell me something, but it tells me nothing:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/apache2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/sbin/apache2-mpm-prefork...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f479782ca9d in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007f479782ca9d in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f4700000002 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f479d2df648 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f479788d11c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f478aebbcf8 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f479b593488 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007f479b593488 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007f4797f450c0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007f479d2df648 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 x00007f479786f81c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00007f479b593488 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007f479786f5b0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#13 0xfffffffffffffff9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x7400737574617473 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x0000000000007375 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x0000000000000009 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007f479cfedd10 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007f478c6ee020 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00007f479d2df648 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

What approach should I try to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should compile apache yourself with the -g option in CFLAGS set. If you use any third-party apache modules then you should also compile them with -g option. [Check this link for more info](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html)